# Getting RequestFailedException: Public access is not permitted on this storage account when accessing Blob Storage in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-identity

Scenario:

I have an Azure Web App that is trying to access a Blob Storage container, and I get the following error: RequestFailedException: Public access is not permitted on this storage account.

I am trying to use Managed Identities for the App to authenticate against the Blob Storage without having to make it public.

They are both in the same VPN, in the same Region

Any idea where it could be going wrong?

Thanks!

**App Service Plan: S1**

[image]

**Some environment variables**

[image: Environment Variables]

**There is the System Assigned Managed Id**

[image]

**The Azure Role Assignments for the Managed Id:**

[image]

**Finally the Code:**

[image]

**And some of the Blob Storage Configuration**

[image]

**They are both in the same VNET**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so Devil is in the details they say.

Even though the container already existed, that line failed throwing the Public Access not allowed which makes complete sense.

Sorry for inconvenience.

[image]

Comment: Not sure this answer is very helpful, for me removing the CreateIfNotExists() line works